# How to share ETS by SNMP in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, snmp

ETS may change content dynamically - keys and values, count of records, can i make this content accessible by SNMP?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've written some JS, so I'll analogize: in JavaScript, this question might read "How to share global object by SNMP in JavaScript?"

That is, ETS is a place to store data. It's a little fancy because there's a process wrapping it, but it's just a language-native data structure. If you want ETS data to be available via SNMP you have to write code to do that.

Comment: Have you any ideas how can i do that? Because content will change, so mib table will be not actual and sharing broke down. Also, i ask about ETS, not for "any structure", because, for example, for Mnesia erlang have [link](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/snmp/snmp_advanced_agent.html#id88200) special functions, that may share it for few clicks.

Comment: Yes, content will change, for example counters, therefore the Ets-table will also update. A MIB is just a specification of which variables you can access with SNMP. It is hard to manage a network without one just using SNMP. SNMP is just a protocol using TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded in Erlang at Ericsson and used both MIB:s and SNMP to manage the network of the AXD 301. And the answer is yes, you can use ETS or even MNESIA tables to access values with SNMP but as the other guy said you have to write the code for it yourself.

Usually you set, or read, the values with SNMP and a MIB accessing your Ets-table, from either a web page (if you have one) or via CLI.

MIB:s and SNMP are connected, it is hard to manage a network without them together. MIB specify which variables you can access or read with SNMP.